# Вставить текст в текущее положение курсора в браузере

Tags: c#, курсор

Необходимо вставить следующий текст в текущее расположение курсора в браузере (если быть точным, то это указание логина и пароля для прокси при авторизации).
Пробовал

```
richTextBox1.SelectedText = "1";
```

но выдает ошибку

> Имя "richTextBox1" не существует в текущем контексте.

Еще можно ли использовать такую конструкцию текста для правильной вставки в нужные поля `login{TAB}pass{TAB}{ENTER}`?

---

В том и проблема что это не веб форма и я не  тип поля,  это всплывающее окно для ввода логина и пароля от прокси в мозилле, просто нужно вставить текст в текущее положение курсора в всплывающем окне

Comment: 1) Если у вас есть поле с именем `richTextBox1`, и у него тип `RichTextBox`, и в нём ссылка на реально существующий и отображаемый приложением контрол, то это должно вставить текст в него. Если нет, то это и не должно откомпилироваться.

Comment: 2) Если фокус находится в нужном контроле, у приложения контрол с паролем находится в tab order'е за коттролом с логином, и ваша строка является аргументом функции `SendKeys`, то да, иначе нет.

Comment: Как я понимаю, нужно вставить текст в окошко самого браузера, а не на веб-странице. В таком случае, смотрите в сторону хуков и WinAPI.